# Getting groups with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

```
{%if Lang="english", Site="testsite"}
content
{%endif}
```

I need to get the groups Lang, Site and the content

This is what I am using to get the content part

```
".*}(.*){%.*"
```

Comment: What have you tried, where is your problem? At the moment the question is only "Do my work for me"

Comment: ".*}(.*){%.*" will give me the content in group 1 not 0

Answer (score 2):

You can capture groups by using `?<groupname>`.

This is a very crude regex to get the groups you want:

```
\{\%if\s.*(Lang=\"(?<lang>[^\"]*))\".*(Site=\"(?<site>[^\"]*))\"\}(?<content>[^\{]*)\{\%endif\}
```

when you use a regex from c# you can get the groups by using:

```
var _regex = new RegEx(...);
var _language = _regex.Groups["lang"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how flexible you need your regex to be, but try something like:

```
{%if Lang="(.*)",\s.*Site="(.*?)"}(\r\n)*?(.*?)(\r\n)*?{%endif}
```

You can then get the matches from there.